# Problem with adding two double values in objective c

Tags: iphone, c, ipad, double

I'm programming an app for iphone and ipad and my program requires adding two double values to get a single double value. The problems is when one of the double values is fairly large (eg: 2^100) and the other one is very small like 1 or 2, the result of adding those two double values is wrong or it doesn't even do the addition. Does anyone know why that is and if there's a way around it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with obj-c. A [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) is a 64-bit datatype that stores a floating-point value. In decimal, a double can hold approximately 15.955 digits of precision. However, your 2^100 number has about 30 decimal digits. So if you try and add anything up to about 1 quadrillion to it, you'll find that the addition doesn't work since that falls outside of the precision range of your number.

In order to get around this, you can use [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will hold up to 38 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: The funny thing is that when i add 2^100 with another 2^100 everything works, but when i add 2^100 to a small number like 1 it stays the same and doesn't add the 1 to 2^100 and that's what i don't understand.

Comment: @Milad: 2^100 + 2^100 will work just fine. Think of a double as scientific notation (because that's basically what it is, except in binary). Google says 2^100 is 1.2676506 × 10^30. If you write that out in "regular" form, you'll notice an awful lot of 0's. But the real number doesn't have all those 0's. The scientific notation number bumped into a precision limit – you'll notice there's only 7 digits after the decimal. That's because a float has roughly 7 decimal digits of precision. If this was a double, there'd be about 15.

Comment: @Milad: I hope it's obvious why adding 2^100 + 2^100 is easy, because adding 1.2676506 × 10^30 to 1.2676506 × 10^30 is easy (you'll get 2.5353012 × 10^30). But if you add 1 instead, how are you going to write that out? You can't without adding another 23 digits to the number, and there's no room for those digits. Basically, when you write 2^100, what you get is a number that represents about 1 quadrillion numbers in that area, because any attempt to calculate any of those quadrillion numbers will hand back the same result as 2^100.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks alot for your answers, it's more clear now. I tried nsdecimalnumber and it does the adding right but still it has limitations. In my app the numbers are pretty large (largest value is about 2^200) and even nsdecimalnumber can't handle adding numbers like that. Is it even possible to do I want to do (eg: add 2^200 and 4 together) or should I try something else?

Comment: @Milad: There are arbitrary-precision arithmetic libraries out there. Wikipedia has a [list of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries). It sounds like you'll need to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good read for anyone dealing with floating-point numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

The situation you describe is completely normal, and is a natural outcome of how floating point works on computers.